# Convert to Datefrom dd/mm/yyyy string SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion

I currently have a string in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` which I'm trying to convert to a datetime variable in SQL.

I'm currently using this SQL statement:

```
CONVERT(datetime, ProposedTransferDate.AttributeValue, 101)
```

but I get an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, `CONVERT()` is a product specific function.

Answer (score 6):

You should be using mask `103`:

```
CONVERT(datetime,ProposedTransferDate.AttributeValue, 103)
```

From [this TechOnTheNet article](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/convert.php) we find that mask 103 has the following format:

> dd/mm/yy (British/French standard)

Answer (score 1):

Use string manipulation to get it into a `yyyy-mm-dd` format:

```
CAST(
    RIGHT(ProposedTransferDate.AttributeValue,4) +
    '-' +
    RIGHT(LEFT(ProposedTransferDate.AttributeValue,5),2) +
    '-' +
    LEFT(ProposedTransferDate.AttributeValue,2)
AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

That conversion error is due to your date column is not **standard and unique SQL/ISO date format**which is YYYY-MM-DD. your date format may be in MM/DD/YYYY so if your login default Language UK means Date format will be like DD/MM/YYYY.So before convert you want change the default language in SQL SERVER .[This link to show types of languages and learn about SET LANGUAGE(TSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql)

EG

```
SET LANGUAGE 'british english'    
select convert(date,GETDATE(),103)         ------------use date then it show only date
```

you can use another way also

```
  SET LANGUAGE 'british english'
select DATEPART(dd,'2-3-2012')+ '/' + DATEPART(mm,'2-3-2012')+ '/' + DATEPART(yy,'2-3-2012')
```

or

```
SET LANGUAGE 'british english'
select CONCAT(DATEPART(dd,'2-3-2012'), '/' , DATEPART(mm,'2-3-2012'), '/' ,DATEPART(yy,'2-3-2012'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/10/2016', 103)
```

Result:
2016-10-23 00:00:00.000